# C WIRE MISSING, Trane Air-Handler Variable 4TEE3F

Tags: electrical

Can you please tell me which wire/contact can I use as a C wire?

[image: H]

[image: Connectors]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you orient your images correctly when posting.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the wiring from the transformer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So just connecting the thermostat wire to the B connector? I have one blue wire loose on both ends (Furnace and Thermostat). Is that all I need to do?

Comment: @MUTLEY looks like it.